# express passport register error on mongodb atlas

Tags: mongoose, passport.js, mongodb-atlas

I'm getting the message below while running the passport register function. I used user/password in the connection string, so I don't know where this admin business came from.

> Mongoose: accounts.findOne({ '$or': [ { username: 'test1' } ] }, { fields: { hash: 0, salt: 0 } })
>   REGISTER err MongoError: cannot do raw queries on admin in atlas

connect command

```
mongoose.set('debug', true)
mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://user:password@cluster*-qns*s.mongodb.net/node-authdb', function(err, client) {
  assert.equal(null, err);
  console.log("Connected successfully to server");
});
```

register code

```
router.post('/register', function(req, res) {
    Account.register(new Account({ username : req.body.username }), req.body.password, function(err, account) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("REGISTER err " + err);
            return res.render('register', { account : account });
        }
```

EDIT

I created a new user (newuser@admin) with dbAdmin@node-authdb (Role) and now I'm having:

> MongoError: user is not allowed to do action [find] on [admin.$cmd]

Maybe there's a specific role combination I need to use?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, I wasn't able to connect to MongoDB Atlas using `mongodb+srv` protocol and at the same time writing in a different database from `admin`. 
You're in a free tier, so you don't have privileges to use certain functions on `admin` database, but even if you upgrade to a paying tier, you'll end up writing in `admin` database. 
So, in the end, I used `replicaSet` for my connection:

```js
// Connect mongoose
const dbCredentials = !_.isEmpty(config.db.user) ? 
`${config.db.user}:${config.db.pwd}@` : '';
let mongooseOptions = {
     autoIndex: true,
};

if (isProduction) {
    mongooseOptions = _.extend(mongooseOptions, {
        ssl: true,
        authSource: 'admin',
        replicaSet: config.db.replicaSet,
    });
}

const uri = `${config.db.protocol}://${dbCredentials}${config.db.host}/${config.db.name}`;
mongoose.connect(uri, mongooseOptions, (err) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error('Could not connect to mongodb', err);
    } else {
        console.log('Connected to mongo', config.db.name);
    }
});

mongoose.set('debug', isDevelopment);
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
```